# ERROR = Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: android, rest, kotlin, retrofit

I have API:

```
import com.poklad.androidtestprojectny.data.remote.model.ResponseCategory
import com.poklad.androidtestprojectny.utils.ApiConstants
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Query

interface NYTimesApi {
    @GET(ApiConstants.GET_ALL_CATEGORIES)
    suspend fun getAllCategories(
        @Query("api-key") apiKey: String = ApiConstants.API_KEY,
    ): List<ResponseCategory>
}
```

Model:

```
    @SerializedName("list_name")
    val listName: String,
    @SerializedName("display_name")
    val displayName: String,
    @SerializedName("list_name_encoded")
    val listNameEncoded: String,
    @SerializedName("oldest_published_date")
    val oldestPublishedDate: String,
    @SerializedName("newest_published_date")
    val newestPublishedDate: String,
    @SerializedName("updated")
    val updated: String
)
```

`Response: { "status": "OK", "copyright": "Copyright (c) 2023 The New York Times Company.  All Rights Reserved.", "num_results": 59, "results": [ { "list_name": "Combined Print and E-Book Fiction", "display_name": "Combined Print & E-Book Fiction", "list_name_encoded": "combined-print-and-e-book-fiction", "oldest_published_date": "2011-02-13", "newest_published_date": "2023-10-08", "updated": "WEEKLY" }, { "list_name": "Combined Print and E-Book Nonfiction", "display_name": "Combined Print & E-Book Nonfiction", "list_name_encoded": "combined-print-and-e-book-nonfiction", "oldest_published_date": "2011-02-13", "newest_published_date": "2023-10-08", "updated": "WEEKLY" },etc.]`

I seem to be doing everything correctly. But I get this error, what to do. Maybe some other inofriation is needed?

I don't know what do`your text`

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because the parser is trying to parse the response as `JsonArray` (as you specified the return type as `List<ResponseCategory>`) but encounters `JsonObject` (the response string starts with `{` instead of `[`).

Basically, there are 2 ways to solve it: create an outer class for `List<ResponseCategory>` that represents the whole response (and, respectively, specify it as the return type) or create a custom `TypeAdapter` (as far as I see, you use Gson, right?):

```
class YourTypeAdapterFactory<T>(private val typeToken: TypeToken<T>) : TypeAdapterFactory {

    override fun <R : Any?> create(gson: Gson, type: TypeToken<R>): TypeAdapter<R>? {
        if (!typeToken.isAssignableFrom(type.type)) {
            return null
        }
        val delegateAdapter = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, typeToken)
        val elementAdapter = gson.getAdapter(JsonElement::class.java)
        val result = object : TypeAdapter<T>() {
            override fun write(out: JsonWriter, value: T) {
                //we don't serialize it so no logic specified
            }

            override fun read(`in`: JsonReader): T? {
                val jsonElement = elementAdapter.read(`in`)
                return delegateAdapter.fromJsonTree(
                    (jsonElement as JsonObject).getAsJsonArray("results")
                )
            }
        }.nullSafe()

        return result as TypeAdapter<R>
    }
}
```

And then it's added to Gson:

```
.registerTypeAdapterFactory(
    YourTypeAdapterFactory(object : TypeToken<List<ResponseCategory>>() {})
)
```